# Pasar datos de vista a controlador en ASP Net Core MVC (Parametros a null)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, razor

Tengo una Vista que se llama `create` que tiene un formulario y llama al controlador `CreateG`.

La vista es esta:

```
@model The_Bell_Ringers_Coop.ViewModels.ViajeConSocioViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Alta de viaje Socio @Model.idSocio </h1>

<h4>Viaje</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-controller="Viajes" asp-action="CreateG">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="grado" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="grado" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="grado" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="KG" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="KG" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="KG" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="idSocio" value="@Model.idSocio" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="idResponsable" value="@Html.ViewData.">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col">Nombre Parcela<br></th>
                        <th class="col">Selección<br></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                @foreach (var item in Model.parcelaCheckboxes)
                {
            <tr>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.parcela.Nombre" value="@item.parcela.Nombre" />
                <td class"">@item.parcela.Nombre</td>

                <td class="">@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.is_checked)</td>
            </tr>
                }

            </table>


            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

y el controlador:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateG(ViajeConSocioViewModel v)
        {
            foreach(var it in v.parcelaCheckboxes)
            {
                if (it.is_checked == true) return RedirectToAction("Details", v);
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Tienes que seleccionar al menos un vehiculo");
            return RedirectToAction("Create", v);
        }
```

y el viewModel seria:

```
public class ViajeConSocioViewModel 
{
     public string idSocio;

     public List<ParcelaCheckbox> parcelaCheckboxes;

     public double KG;

     public double grado;

     public string idResponsable;

}
```

La Clase `ParcelaCheckbox` simplemente tiene un atributo `int` `porcentaje`, otro que es de tipo `bool` que es `is_Cheked` y un objeto de tipo parcela que tiene un atributo de tipo `string` que se llama Nombre.

Mi problema es que al pasar parámetros me devuelve `null` en vez de un objeto tipo `ViajeConSocioViewModel`.

Probando otras maneras he visto que si paso al controlador los elementos uno a uno si que me los recoge todos excepto la lista de `parcelaCheckbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te das cuenta, estás usando **campos** en vez de **propiedades** en el `ViewModel` que pasas al Controlador.

Para que ASP.NET realice correctamente el **data-binding** de los datos, es necesario que utilices propiedades del tipo `{ get; set; }`.

```
public class ViajeConSocioViewModel 
{
    public string idSocio { get; set; };

    public List<ParcelaCheckbox> parcelaCheckboxes { get; set; };

    public double KG { get; set; };

    public double grado { get; set; };

    public string idResponsable { get; set; };

}
```